# R Sweave "not run" option

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I use Sweave in R to make a package vignette and would like to know if there is a way to "not run" certain code within a Sweave tag, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<a>>=
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz",depend=TRUE)
@

<<<b>>=
x <- 1
cat(x, "\n")
@ 

\end{document}
```

Is there an option in Sweave to not run the code in the  `<<a>>=` tag? (I could simply use "verbatim" instead of a Sweave tag, but is there something like a "not run" as for Rd files?) I looked into the options in the Sweave User Manual, but did not find what I am looking for.

Comment: Not sure but I'm guessing so because you can do that with knitr which I believe uses Sweave (could be wrong on this).  Also as of yesterday (R 3.0.0) [we can make vignettes with knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/) including markdown. You may want to consider the switch regardless of the answer you may get here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm using R 2.14.1, but have not looked into knitr at all...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `eval` option on your code chunk. Something like :

```
<<a, eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE>>=
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz",depend=TRUE)
@
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I saw it now, in the Sweave manual, the 'eval' option is in the documentation for 'RweaveLatex'.